# windows 8.1 not updating

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro. For last one month, I am not receiving any update. As, I have always enabled automatic update, this not receiving any update seemed suspicious to me. I manually checked for update. It just checking for without any result like being in an infinite loop.

Then I used update troubleshooter that resolved the following issues.

```
Potential Windows Update Database error detected  Ox80070490 ------ Fixed
Windows Update Components Must be repaired ------------------------ Fixed
```

But that doesn't make any effect in checking for updates. Every time I use troubleshooter, it keeps resolving the same issues.

** Windows defender becomes Updated automatically without any problem though.

What should I do ??

Comment: Hmmmm.....it might be due to problems on your machine with Windows Genuine Advantage.   Find mgadiag.exe, download it and run it to see if there are any problems there.

Comment: Maybe due to a disk error. Try running a chkdisk, if that doesn't find anything, you would need to use a dedicated utility such as SpinRite.

Comment: @mdpc, `mgadiag.exe` saying `validation unsupported os`. do you have any idea why so ? I am using genuine windows.

Comment: @JulianKnight, chkdisk is giving clear report. and I think SpinRite isn't open source. is there any such free software?